# iOS Public method to acces property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hi this is my first question and I'm wording about the problem I'm facing hope any one can help

i have a public method in class i included called +(void)show
 which should change the alpha of a property

thats whats im doing

```
+(void)show
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.O.alpha=1;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //
                     }];

//... code
}
```

but it gives me an error any one knows why or how to solve it ? thanks in advance

Comment: self in static method is undefined

Comment: self.0.alpha is incorrect, even if it were an instance method. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: its not 0 its O which where i have @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *O;

Comment: From where the `show` method is called? It is supposed to show the imageView, am I right?

Comment: show is called from other class and it should show the imgView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because this is a class method, and you can't access properties in a class method. Make it an instance method by changing the `+` to a `-`.

Comment: but i need to make it public method to be called from the other class who import this class in

Comment: You can still do that, you just need an instance of the class to be created, like this `MyClass *object = [[MyClass alloc] init];` and call `[object show];`

Comment: @ChrisLoonam That is a bad advice. You shouldn't create an object just  to call its instance method!

Comment: nope it doesn't show the method show if i make it instance method

Comment: @iJazJaz What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks it seems all i needed it to put the method in the header .. thanks aloooot

Comment: @KhanhNguyen It's not bad advice. It's pretty clear from the use of `self` with properties that the OP intends `show` to be an instance method, not a class method. Besides that, a method named `show` probably doesn't make much sense as a class method -- you can't "show" a class. As the OP has written it, `self` refers to the class object, not to an instance of the class.